# Can't call the method and display it an apex repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat, method

Hi I have the following problem. I wrote a class that would display events on a visual force page but it doesn't seem to be working as it should. The query is now fixed and it is allowed to be passed by an anonymous user however the events don't get displayed. Can anyone give me a hand? I don't know what I;m doing wrong

Here is the apex class

```
public with sharing class HarborEventController {
private final Event__c eventlist;
public HarborEventController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.eventlist = (Event__c)controller.getRecord();
    this.eventlist.displayevets();
    HarborEventController = new HarborEventController();
}


public Integer eventcount{get;set;}
public HarborEventController (){
   eventcount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Event__c];    
}

public list<Event__c> mainlist {get;set;}  
public list<Event__c> displayevents(){
    mainlist = new list<Event__c>();
    String mainsoql = 'SELECT Id, Name__C, Message__c, Display_Date__c FROM Event__c '; 
    mainsoql += 'ORDER BY Display_date__c LIMIT 5';
    mainlist = Database.query(mainsoql);
    return mainlist;        
}}
```

system.debug(mainlist);

and visualforce page:

```
    <apex:composition template="eh_base">
          <apex:define name="heros-content">  
          </apex:define>
      <apex:define name="content">
       <section id="services-sec">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 60px;">


    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISNULL(mainlist)),mainlist.size>0)}">
        <apex:form id="blockofeventtorepeat">


            <apex:repeat value="{!mainlist}" var="evententry" id="repeat">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                   <h3><apex:outputLink styleClass="evententry-header block" value="{!$Page.eh_eventdetails}?id={!evententry.id}">{!evententry.Name__c}</apex:outputLink></h3>
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                     <p>
                         <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Harbor_Resources_img1, 'img/16.jpg')}" class="img-responsive center-block" height="42" alt=""/>

                         {!evententry.Message__c}
                     </p>
                       <apex:outputLink styleclass="btn btn-sm btn-default" value="{!$Page.eh_eventdetails}?id={!evententry.id}">Read More</apex:outputLink>

                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </div>
                </apex:repeat>



                </apex:form>
                </apex:outputPanel> 

                </div>
            </div>




            </section>      
    </apex:define>
</apex:composition>
```

Comment: Maybe You don't have Events in database? :) Or Your user dont have access to them. From that You described, everything works, no errors, but no event displayed,yes? Try make class `public WITHOUT sharing`

Comment: The event is set up and the query returns results, I've  already set the security settings of the pages and classes involved. no it doesnt

Comment: This could be issue with events sharing, did You Tried `public WITHOUT sharing`? This way we will check sharing issues

Comment: Yes, the class still seems to fail

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts also don't post duplicates. You already had an answer in the linked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted there did not appear to be a call to `displayevents` but perhaps you had that in the page action.

I would structure the code like this:

```
public with sharing class HarborEventController {

    // Properties the page can reference
    public Integer eventcount {get;set;}
    public List<Event__c> mainlist {get;set;} 

    public HarborEventController (){
        init();  
    }

    public HarborEventController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        eventcount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Event__c];

        String soql = ''
                + 'SELECT Id, Name__C, Message__c, Display_Date__c '
                + 'FROM Event__c '
                + 'ORDER BY Display_date__c '
                + 'LIMIT 5'
                ;
        mainlist = (List<Event__c>) Database.query(soql);       
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, it seems that on the line 20 there is an error that states that the expressions cannot be a statement

Comment: @Greg I left in a spurious `;` that I've just removed.